# How does one determine if a character (Unicode Code Point) is Left-to-Right or Right-to-Left?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I have an answer below. If someone has a better answer, please comment.

One would like to think one could use "UnicodeData....txt" to work out what is
left-to-right or right-to-left text. Unfortunately not, because this list goes on a per-character
style, ignoring the concept of the "block". In other words, consider an Arabic or Hebrew block: not
all code-points are defined, but OBVIOUSLY if a code point is added in the Hebrew block is is NOT
going to be the single one in the block that is Left-to-Right -- that would be extremely unlikely.
Close inspection of all the right-to-left characters while cross-referencing the block names reveals
there are only five ranges of characters that are right to left. These five ranges cover all
right-to-left character blocks, and all ranges of characters where a newly-defined right-to-left
code point is likely to be inserted.

I was able to determine that there are the following Right-to-left blocks in Unicode 10.

```
0590..05FF; Hebrew
0600..06FF; Arabic
0700..074F; Syriac
0750..077F; Arabic Supplement
0780..07BF; Thaana
07C0..07FF; NKo
0800..083F; Samaritan
0840..085F; Mandaic
0860..086F; Syriac Supplement
08A0..08FF; Arabic Extended-A

FB1D..FB4F; Alphabetic Presentation Forms (hebrew part)
FB50..FDFF; Arabic Presentation Forms-A
FE70..FEFF; Arabic Presentation Forms-B

10800..1083F; Cypriot Syllabary
10840..1085F; Imperial Aramaic
10860..1087F; Palmyrene
10880..108AF; Nabataean
108E0..108FF; Hatran
10900..1091F; Phoenician
10920..1093F; Lydian
10980..1099F; Meroitic Hieroglyphs
109A0..109FF; Meroitic Cursive
10A00..10A5F; Kharoshthi
10A60..10A7F; Old South Arabian
10A80..10A9F; Old North Arabian
10AC0..10AFF; Manichaean
10B00..10B3F; Avestan
10B40..10B5F; Inscriptional Parthian
10B60..10B7F; Inscriptional Pahlavi
10B80..10BAF; Psalter Pahlavi
10C00..10C4F; Old Turkic
10C80..10CFF; Old Hungarian

1E800..1E8DF; Mende Kikakui
1E900..1E95F; Adlam
1EE00..1EEFF; Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols
```

Here is an optimized C language comparator macro: most common text will stop at the first '>='.

This macro is correct for every code point in unicode 10 except for:

```
200F;RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK;Cf;0;R;;;;;N;;;;;
```

Macro (The word "levant" is an approximately good description of most Right-to-Left languages):

```c
#define IS_LEVANT(c)  ((c) >= 0x00590 && ((c) <= 0x008FF || \
                      ((c) >= 0x0FB1D && ((c) <= 0x0FDFF || \
                      ((c) >= 0x0FE70 && ((c) <= 0x0FEFF || \
                      ((c) >= 0x10800 && ((c) <= 0x10CFF || \
                      ((c) >= 0x1E800 && ((c) <= 0x1EEFF))))))))))
```

Here is a Python script to test the macro:

```py
f = open('/home/paul/UnicodeData.txt').readlines()

def LEVANT(c):
    return \
                      ((c) >= 0x00590 and ((c) <= 0x008FF or \
                      ((c) >= 0x0FB1D and ((c) <= 0x0FDFF or \
                      ((c) >= 0x0FE70 and ((c) <= 0x0FEFF or \
                      ((c) >= 0x10800 and ((c) <= 0x10CFF or \
                      ((c) >= 0x1E800 and ((c) <= 0x1EEFF))))))))))

for ll in f:
    ll = ll.strip()
    if not ll:
        continue
    l = ll.split(';')
    if l[4] == 'R':
        i = l[0]
        i = eval('0x' + i)
        if not LEVANT(i):
            print('R ===> ' + ll)
    if l[4] == 'L':
        i = l[0]
        i = eval('0x' + i)
        if LEVANT(i):
            print('R ===> ' + ll)
```

Comment: Do you mean https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/tr9-37.html ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is an accepted pattern to post both a question and an answer here. BUT: you should divide this into separate question and answer posts. Use the "answer your own question" button and move the answer part of your post there.

Comment: The unicode report is too complicated. I just want to know whether a character is right-to-left or left-to-right.

Comment: many characters are bidirectional so you can't simply tell whether they're LTR or RTL just by looking at the code point. You must use a Unicode library like ICU and give them the context to parse

Answer (score 0):

The Bidi class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Bidi.html) will analyze a character array and indicate the number of runs in it (sections where text is either RTL or LTR), where the runs start and stop and if the runs are LTR or RTL